# Counting items in GroupBy by group.key in Angular with rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a very large array of items where there is a "Status" field that could have one of six statuses.  Using the rxjs library, I am trying to .groupBy then .reduce to return an array of the six statuses and the count of items with those statuses.

Here is the method in my service:

```
getStatusTotals() {
        return Observable.from(sampleData)
            .map(res => res.d.results)
            .concatMap(data => data)
            .groupBy(item => item.Status)
            .mergeMap(group => group
                .reduce((total, item) => total, 0)
                .map(total => ({ Status: group.key, Count: total }))
                )
            .toArray()

    }
```

In the component where I am calling this service function, I set the value to statusData and the information is being presented as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let t of tracdata | async" class="row">Status: {{t.Status}}; Count: {{t.Count}}</div>
```

This, however is giving me the following in my app:

```
Status: 5 - Dormant; Count: 0
Status: 2 - Active; Count: 0
Status: 4 - Assigned to Section; Count: 0
Status: 1 - Pending Review; Count: 0
Status: 3 - Officer Review; Count: 0
```

So I am doing something wrong.  I have tried .count and .forEach, and read through the rxjs documentation, but I must be doing something wrong.  Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reduce is missing +1 for actually counting the statuses

```
.reduce((total, item) => total + 1, 0)
```

Anyway, you can replace the .reduce(..) with .count()

Comment: Yes! I tried this one first so marking this as the answer.  I changed .reduce to .count, as you suggested as follows ".count((status, item) => item == item)" and this returned the correct result! Many thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! I think .count() with no predicate also works

Comment: Ah nice, true! I removed the predicate: ".count(item => item == item)", and this also works.  I wish I understood rxjs as well as you do!

Comment: I now have to retrieve the results using this.http.get(this.restapi){}.  I added ".map(res => res.json())" just above the first .map line (and I feel like I've tried a billion other things to get it to work) however, it's still not working.  Any words of advice or what to do to get this working again?

Answer (score 1):

As @ZahiC said, `reduce` will work.

But `reduce` will only emit once you've got all the data.

If you want to compute all of that every time there's a `next`, you should use `scan` instead.

Here's an example :

```
const { Observable } = Rx;

const sampleData = [
  { status: 'status1' },
  { status: 'status2' },
  { status: 'status1' },
  { status: 'status3' },
  { status: 'status4' },
  { status: 'status2' },
  { status: 'status5' },
  { status: 'status6' },
  { status: 'status4' }
];

Observable
  .from(sampleData)
  .scan((acc, curr) => {
    const status = curr.status;
    const count = acc[status] ? acc[status].count : 0;

    return Object.assign(acc, {
      [status]: { status, count: count + 1 }
    });
  }, {})
  .do(console.log)
  .subscribe();
```

And a working Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/U2mZC5QpL12NpuHTJOFq?p=preview

**EDIT:**

As this function gives an `object` and you want an array, I've added a small function for that :

```
const objToArray = (obj) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  return keys.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, obj[curr]], []);
}
```

Then I just `map` the `Observable` to it before the `do` :

```
...
.map(objToArray)
.do(console.log)
.subscribe();
```

The output is the following :

[image]

*(notice that we have the intermediate results !)*

Comment: What does this line do: " const count = acc[status] ? acc[status].count : 0;"  I'm familiar with what most of the rest of your code is doing, is that the same as the elvis operator?

Comment: it's a "ternary operator". It's the equivalent of a simple if/else. It says : is `acc[status]` defined and not considered as falsy (!= undefined, null, false, empty string ...). If yes, return the count for that status otherwise return 0. (0 is to initialize in fact). You can take a look to ternary operator  also here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/conditional-ternary-operator-decrement-javascript